# Why is stdout in libc?

Tags: c, assembly, binary, libc

**Question**

Why is the stdout variable in a binary linked to a libc address?

And what's at this specific libc address?

Comment: Where else do you suppose it should be? It's something provided by libc. It's a `FILE*`. What exactly that is, is an implementation detail.

Comment: I expected the stdout FILE* to be saved in a variable in the binary because it's not for every binary the same or am I wrong?

Comment: I mean if you start the binary in two different terminals they don't have the same stdout or not? So it shouldn't be globally be in the libc because then both would have the same stdout @Jester

Comment: As far as libc is concerned they are the same stdout. On unix-like systems stdio stuff eventually ends up using file descriptors which for stdout is `1`. So the `FILE*` can be the same too. The difference is handled in the OS itself as it's maintaining an open file table for each process.

Answer (score 2):

The `FILE` object pointed to by `FILE *stdout` may be allocated at runtime by the libc init functions, for libc implementations like glibc that need init functions to be called before `main` runs.

> So it shouldn't be globally be in the libc because then both would have the same stdout

Every process has its own `stdout` pointer, pointing to its own `FILE` object, **because the data section of shared libraries are private mappings.**

Different processes using the same library don't have shared memory for read-write data.